# Can I order rows in my pivot table by aggregate value in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, pivot-table

Hi I'm studying for the querying Microsoft server certification hence the use of the TSQL2012 server datasource. This is not homework but just exploration of the topics.

The big picture is I'm trying to have a pivot table with the sales per customer(companyname) broken down by order year. however I am trying to order the rows of the the pivot table so that the company with the highest sales over the all years (three in this case) is at the top of the list.

```
    WITH basedata as(
select  
    companyname as Company
    ,Year(orderdate) as [Order Year] 
    ,((unitprice*qty)*(1-discount)) AS Sales 
from 
    sales.Orders as o
right join Sales.MyCustomers as n
    ON o.custid = n.custid
join Sales.OrderDetails as d
    ON d.orderid = o.orderid
)SELECT 
     Company, [2006],[2007],[2008] 
FROM 
     basedata
pivot
     (sum(Sales) FOR [Order Year] in ([2006],[2007],[2008])) 
as PVT
Order by 
     sum(Sales);
```

I get the error below

```
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
    Invalid column name 'Sales'.
```

Comment: No, there is no such column `Sales` in the `PIVOT`. Do you want to order the data by the `SUM` of  `Sales` of each `Company` all time?

Comment: You can't do it directly, you would need to add up the columns and order by that, e.g `ORDER BY pvt.[2006] + pvt.[2007] + pvt.[2008]`. Although, `SUM` can be `NULL` so you probably want to use `ISNULL` for each of your columns: `ORDER BY ISNULL(pvt.[2006], 0) + ISNULL(pvt.[2007], 0) + ISNULL(pvt.[2008], 0)`.

Comment: @gotqn yes i am interested in ordering based on the sales of all three years for each company

Comment: @GarethD thanks that worked fine I just included a DESC and it was just as I had hoped for thanks for your prompt response and your assistance

Answer (score 0):

The way to order the pivot table so that the top row of the pivot  table had the company with the highest sales for the three years combined while also taking into consideration fact that some companies could have had a null value for sales (ISNULL function replaced a null value with 0)  was to

```
    ORDER BY ISNULL(pvt.[2006], 0) + ISNULL(pvt.[2007], 0) 
    + ISNULL(pvt.[2008], 0) DESC;
```